# Need to rerun script after error or exception is risen

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Need to rerun my selenium python script after either a 'list index is out of range' error or the page does not load and throughs some error or exception that has to due with it timing out. And no, upping the time for the page to load does not help, since it will continuously try to load. So is there a way to make the script stop and restart on its own if it encounters a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
while True:
    try:
        <your script>
    except <error>:
        pass
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

@kevin You are right. But this question needs little more.

```
def initiate_test_condition():
    """
    This should have the initial setup (Environment where your testcase to be tested)
    Example:
    * reopening your browser and 
    * kill all already opened browsers
    """
    pass

def test_case_flow():
    """
    write your selenium testing code
    """
    initiate_test_condition()
    try:
        """
        your testing code
        """     
        # if all code runs successfully
        return 1
    except Exception as error:
        print str(error)
        return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    total_rerun = 0
    while True:
        if total_rerun != 5 and total_rerun < 5:
            if test_case_flow():
                print "Looks like the code is passed :)"
                return or break
            else:
                total_rerun += 1
                print "Rerunning the code"
        else:
            print "Code Failed after rerunning %d times "  % total_rerun
            break
```